# JQuery img url filled with variable

Tags: jquery

I have variable:

```
$place = "images/img1.jpg";
```

I want to tell image's url to use the variable.

```
$('div.bg2').css("background-image", "url($place)");
```

But this doesn't work. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String concatination is not proper, in your case `$place` is just a part of the string literal, you need to concatenate your string with the actual value of the variable `$place`. Try

```
$('div.bg2').css("background-image", "url(" + $place+ ")");
```

Comment: @TomsBugna What is meant byu doesn't work? You need to have height and width for the div as well. It is background image.

Comment: Everything is fine with that. When the code is like this $('div.bg2').css("background-image", "url("images/img1.jpg")"); then everything works. When with variable like in Your style, then doesn't work.

Comment: @TomsBugna can you replicate it in a fiddle? Is your image url right? See this example http://jsfiddle.net/jSmLE/

Comment: Sorry. One mistake in that fiddle: in css .bg2 isn't the line where is added the background-img url. There should be only two lines (height and width)

Comment: @TomsBugna WHat is the issue? i see the image. Again you did string concat mistake it should be http://jsfiddle.net/VExmF/